# Error - Connect-MsolService : Your credentials could not be authenticated. Try again

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-active-directory

In Powershell, I executed the below cmdlets

Connect-MsolService

Getting error like below

```
Connect-MsolService : Your credentials could not be authenticated. Try again
or contact Technical Support.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-MsolService
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], Mic
   rosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 0x80048820,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Autom
   ation.ConnectMsolService
```

I am giving the credentials of Azure portal account, what is wrong with this ? What credentials should I give ?

Tried below link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj151815.aspx#BKMK_connect   -- 
I have latest version of MSOL libraries.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2412085  -- I am able open the azure management portal.

The below link says "Enter the user name and password of your B2C tenant administrator account."

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/

I am using the username, that is co-administrator for the Azure Portal. Is it possible the co-administrator can connect to the MSOL Services.

Please suggest.

Comment: I was able to over come with this issue, the problem was, my user name was co-administrator, when I execute the "Connect-MsolService" with **global administrator**, I was able to proceed.

Comment: This link has some details may be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044861/several-azure-ad-new-msolserviceprincipal-access-denied

Answer (score 3):

I had excatly the same problem. I solved it with creating a new Global Administrator as already mentioned.

Just wantend to state that:

-this must be done in the old portal, not the new one

-adding a native account to that AAD B2C, guest accounts do not work

Comment: I was having this problem as well and this helped. Also, it seems the new portal is able to be used for creating these accounts now.

Answer (score 0):

The account you are using must be assigned the role of (Global) Administrator in Azure Active Directory as stated by the document you referenced:

> Before you can create applications or users, or interact with Azure AD
>   at all, you will need an Azure AD B2C tenant and a global
>   administrator account in the tenant.

By default, all co-administrator accounts are added to Azure AD in 'Member' role.

Comment: I have assigned role to the user as mentioned in this article, but it doesn't help. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-assign-admin-roles/